# Removing duplicates with no sets, no for loops, maintain order and update the original list

Tags: python-3.x, duplicates

Ok, so I have to remove duplicates from a list and maintain order at the same time. However, there are certain conditions such as I'm not allowed to use set or for loops. Also when the function mustn't return a new list but update the original list. I have the following code, but it only works partially and yes I know I'm only checking once, but I'm not sure how to proceed further.

```
def clean_list(values):
    i = len(values)-1
    while i > 0:
        if values[i] ==  values[i-1]:
            values.pop(i)
        i -= 1
    return values

values = [1, 2, 0, 1, 4, 1, 1, 2, 2, 5, 4, 3, 1, 3, 3, 4, 2, 4, 3, 1, 3, 0, 3, 0, 0]
new_values = clean_list(values)
print(new_values)
```

Gives me the result:

```
 [1, 2, 0, 1, 4, 1, 2, 5, 4, 3, 1, 3, 4, 2, 4, 3, 1, 3, 0, 3, 0]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following.

Using two while loops, the first will get your unique item, the second will then search through the rest of the list for any other matching items and remove them, maintaining order.

```
def clean_list(lst):
    i = 0
    while i < len(lst):
        item = lst[i] # item to check
        j = i + 1 # start next item along
        while j < len(lst):
            if item == lst[j]:
                lst.pop(j)
            else:
                j += 1
        i += 1

values = [1, 2, 0, 1, 4, 1, 1, 2, 2, 5, 4, 3, 1, 3, 3, 4, 2, 4, 3, 1, 3, 0, 3, 0, 0]
clean_list(values)
print(values)

# Output
[1, 2, 0, 4, 5, 3]
```

---

**Update:** Improved function to be faster as worst case the first one was O(n2)

```
def clean_list(lst):
    seen = set()
    i = 0
    while i < len(lst):
        item = lst[i]
        if item in seen:
            lst.pop(i)
        else:
            seen.add(item)
            i += 1

values = [1, 2, 0, 1, 4, 1, 1, 2, 2, 5, 4, 3, 1, 3, 3, 4, 2, 4, 3, 1, 3, 0, 3, 0, 0]
clean_list(values)
print(values)

# Output
[1, 2, 0, 4, 5, 3]
```